# Efficiently finding duplicates in a constrained many-to-many dataset?

Tags: java, data-structures, duplicates

I have to write a bulk operation version of something our webapp
lets you do on a more limited basis from the UI.  The desired
operation is to assign objects to a category.  A category can have
multiple objects but a given object can only be in one category.

The workflow for the task is:

1) Using the browser, a file of the following form is uploaded:

```
# ObjectID, CategoryID
Oid1, Cid1
Oid2, Cid1
Oid3, Cid2
Oid4, Cid2
[etc.]
```

The file will most likely have tens to hundreds of lines, but
definitely could have thousands of lines.

In an ideal world a given object id would only occur once in the file
(reflecting the fact that an object can only be assigned to one category)
But since the file is created outside of our control, there's no guarantee
that's actually true and the processing has to deal with that possibility.

2) The server will receive the file, parse it, pre-process it
   and show a page something like:

```
723 objects to be assigned to 126 categories
142 objects not found
 42 categories not found

Do you want to continue?

[Yes]     [No]
```

3) If the user clicks the `Yes` button, the server will
   actually do the work.

Since I don't want to parse the file in both steps (2) and (3), as
part of (2), I need to build a container that will live across
requests and hold a useful representation of the data that will let me
easily provide the data to populate the "preview" page and will let me
efficiently do the actual work.  (While obviously we have sessions, we
normally keep very little in-memory session state.)

There is an existing

```
assignObjectsToCategory(Set<ObjectId> objectIds, CategoryId categoryId)
```

function that is used when assignment is done through the UI.  It is
highly desireable for the bulk operation to also use this API since it
does a bunch of other business logic in addition to the simple
assignment and we need that same business logic to run when this bulk
assign is done.

Initially it was going to be OK that if the file "illegally" specified
multiple categories for a given object -- it would be OK to assign the
object abitrarily to one of the categories the file associated it
with.

So I was initially thinking that in step (2) as I went through the
file I would build up and put into the cross-request container a
`Map<CategoryId, Set<ObjectId>>` (specifically a `HashMap` for quick
lookup and insertion) and then when it was time to do the work I could
just iterate on the map and for each `CategoryId` pull out the
associated `Set<ObjectId>` and pass them into `assignObjectsToCategory()`.

However, the requirement on how to handle duplicate `ObjectId`s changed.
And they are now to be handled as follows:

- If an `ObjectId` appears multiple times in the file and
  all times is associated with the same `CategoryId`, assign
  the object to that category.
- If an `ObjectId` appears multiple times in the file and
  is associated with different `CategoryId`s, consider that
  an error and make mention of it on the "preview" page.

That seems to mess up my `Map<CategoryId, Set<ObjectId>>` strategy
since it doesn't provide a good way to detect that the `ObjectId` I
just read out of the file is already associated with a `CategoryId`.

So my question is how to most efficiently detect and track these
duplicate `ObjectId`s?

What came to mind is to use both "forward" and "reverse" maps:

```
public CrossRequestContainer
{
    ...

    Map<CategoryId, Set<ObjectId>> objectsByCategory;  // HashMap
    Map<ObjectId, List<CategoryId>> categoriesByObject; // HashMap
    Set<ObjectId> illegalDuplicates;

    ...
}
```

Then as each `(ObjectId, CategoryId)` pair was read in, it would
get put into both maps.  Once the file was completely read in, I
could do:

```
for (Map.Entry<ObjectId, List<CategoryId>> entry : categoriesByObject.entrySet()) {
    List<CategoryId> categories = entry.getValue();
    if (categories.size() > 1) {
        ObjectId object = entry.getKey();
        if (!all_categories_are_equal(categories)) {
            illegalDuplicates.add(object);
            // Since this is an "illegal" duplicate I need to remove it
            // from every category that it appeared with in the file.
            for (CategoryId category : categories) {
                objectsByCategory.get(category).remove(object);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When this loop finishes, `objectsByCategory` will no longer contain any "illegal"
duplicates, and `illegalDuplicates` will contain all the "illegal" duplicates to 
be reported back as needed.  I can then  iterate over `objectsByCategory`, get the `Set<ObjectId>` for each category, and call `assignObjectsToCategory()` to do the assignments.

But while I think this will work, I'm worried about storing the data twice, especially
when the input file is huge.  And I'm also worried that I'm missing something re: efficiency
and this will go very slowly.

Are there ways to do this that won't use double memory but can still run quickly?
Am I missing something that even with the double memory use will still run a lot
slower than I'm expecting?

Comment: You should use the **[collections](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release09/javadoc/index.html)** of **[Guava Libraries](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/)**

Comment: If a user chooses to proceed when there are illegal assignments, what do you want to have happen?

Comment: Have you actually profiled the memory and time performance of your implementation or is this a theoretical worry?

Comment: 1) It's theoretical in that I haven't started writing the code yet.  2) If there are illegal assignments, they need to be ignored (not acted on).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the constraints you've given, I don't there's a way to do this using a lot less memory.

One possible optimization though is to only maintain lists of categories for objects which are listed in multiple categories, and otherwise just map object to category, ie:

```
Map<CategoryId, Set<ObjectId>> objectsByCategory;  // HashMap
Map<ObjectId, CategoryId> categoryByObject; // HashMap
Map<ObjectId, Set<CategoryId>> illegalDuplicates;  // HashMap
```

Yes, this adds yet another container, but it will contain (hopefully) only a few entries; also, the memory requirements of the categoryByObject map is reduced (cutting out one list overhead per entry).

The logic is a little more complicated of course. When a duplicate is initially discovered, the object should be removed from the categoryByObject map and added into the illegalDuplicates map. Before adding any object into the categoryByObject map, you will need to first check the illegalDuplicates map.

Finally, it probably won't hurt performance to build the objectsByCategory map in a separate loop *after* building the other two maps, and it will simplify the code a bit.